# $\bigcup \alpha$ where $\alpha$ is a finite ordinal.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given a finite ordinal, is it correct in saying $\bigcup \alpha = \alpha - 1$?

As an illustrative example consider $3 = \{\emptyset , \{\emptyset\}, \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}\}$.

I believe $\bigcup 3 = \{\emptyset , \{\emptyset\}\} = 2$.

Is this accurate?

Comment: Not for $\alpha=0$ ($\bigcup{\emptyset}=\emptyset$) (this is the only limit ordinal you need to worry about though since you're only looking at the finite case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $\alpha=\beta+1=\beta\cup\{\beta\}$ where $\beta$ is an ordinal (note that this is applicable for all *nonzero* finite ordinals, but also for many infinite ones). Then $x\in\bigcup\alpha$ iff $x\in y$ for some $y\in \alpha$. And this is equivalent to $x\in\beta$ or $x\in y$ for some $y\in \beta$. Since $x\in y\in \beta$ implies $x\in \beta$ as well, we ultimately have 
$$ x\in\bigcup\alpha\iff x\in\beta$$
which means $$ \bigcup\alpha=\beta.$$